# what does (object) mean in php?

Tags: php, drupal-7

```
$comment = (object) $comment;
```

i'm  a php novice. i've come across this line of code in drupal's comment module and don't understand what "(object)" does here? Thank you

Comment: It's a [typecast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php displays exactly this cast.

Comment: you make from one array like ["x" => 2] and call it like $y['x'] to an object {"x" => 2} which you call via $y->x. Array to stdClass typecasting.

Comment: Why are you providing answers in the comments?

Answer (score 1):

It's a way of Type casting. PHP will attempt to cast the value in $comment to an Object.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 0):

It typecasts $comment to ensure that it acts like an object later in the code. This allows you to avoid having to do a "if(is_object($comment))" check later when you want to act on the object.

If it's not an object, and you attempt to use the "object->property" notation, PHP will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

It basically says that the variable `$comment` is the datatype object, and if it is not it will typecast the datatype of `$comment` to a object.

The syntax is used mainly to Type Cast but because php is really flexible with data types it is often not necessary.

You could use type casting like this:

```
$number = '22';

doesometing((int) $number); // A function that only accepts integers
```